# WSO2 ESB How to upload app config xml files

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to work around a weird behaviour of WSO2 ESB. Whenever the ESB is started, all carbon files are redeployed. This means to reset all changes made in files after last deploy(restart), such us, configuration xml files (endpoints, custom config files...) .

So I guess the only way to avoid modifing this configuration files during the start up is to take them out from the carbon file. Thus, I would upload app files as carbon app, and app config files (EP, custom config files...) using an alternative way.

So, in this situation, how could I upload these config files in and easy and automatic way?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using a CApp (Carbon Application) to deploy the esb artifacts like endpoints. The number rule for this procedure is that you need to do all the modifications you need to do via the WSO2 Developer Studio, build a CApp, and re-deploy it in WSO2 ESB. You should try to avoid using management console to perform esb artifact (proxy services, endpoints, sequences, templates etc.) modifications. You can of course use the management console for other administrative tasks like configuring data-sources, BAM mediation data publishing etc.

If you are using the Management console to modify artifacts, then you can do that too, but avoid using CApps as the method of deploying esb artifacts. You should probably copy all the config xml files to relevant folders at `$ESB_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/`. And then go ahead with your modifications via mgt console.